# Wireless card doesn't work for an HP DV2104

Tags: 11.10, wireless, hp

HP laptop upgraded from 10.10 to 11.10, model DV2104.  I used a wired connection for the install, but now it does not even seem to recognise that there is a wireless card.  I think I need help with this one.

Question input on another connected device!

Installed WICD & WICD network manager & removed network manager - using Software Centre. Wired connection is OK, but WICD NM says there are no wireless networks available although I am less than 6ft from a (working) wireless router.

The hardware wireless switch on the HP is at left for on, but the light shows orange ! (it's normally blue when connected wirelessly)

STUMPED !!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with a HP DV5000 series laptop, so it may not be the same as yours, but maybe you can use some of the steps to get you in the right place.

1st you need to identify your driver, and they way I do that is get a list of my hardware on my computer.  Open terminal and see if the program that you need is installed.  More than likely it is.`sudo apt-get install lshw`  lshw is a Hardware Lister.  If and when the program is loaded, now you can send a copy of your hardware to your home folder and you can save it in you Ubuntu One or Dropbox folder to keep as long as you have your laptop.  Now in terminal type `sudo lshw -html > your-file-name.html` and if you want you can change where it says your-file-name to whatever you want.  When the program is complete just go to your home folder and open the html file created.  It should open with Firefox, Chromium, Chrome... When it is open, scroll down to where your wireless lan controller, it should look like this.
[image]
Under configuration on my laptop it says its a b43 driver.  Now I downloaded the older Synaptic Package Manager in the USC (Ubuntu Software Center).  After downloading I opened the Synaptic Package Manager a did a search on B43 and this is what I got;
[image]
Notice what choices I made and the choices I did not make.  If we are lucky and the drivers are same, all should work.  If you have a different driver then search what your driver is.  With a little good luck it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to install [WICD](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/download.php)? It worked great for me! Download and install it, then remove network-manager.